# Bitmask for modulo on Unsigned int

Tags: c, bitmask

What Bitmask to use for modulo division by 256 on an unsigned int in C language? Also how should one go about figuring this out?

Comment: The answer for `% 256` is 0xFF, aka 255.  For modulo `2**N` (2 to the power of N), use `2**N - 1`, aka `((1U << N) - 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use all bits that are less significant than the 256-bit.

So, in this case, that would be the 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2 and 1-bit. The resulting bitmask would therefore be 0b11111111 = 0xff.

In C, a resulting code could be `j & 0xff`. But that manual translation is usually unnecessary, you can also use `j % 256`. If you want to use bitmasks for performance reasons, don't worry, the compiler will usually optimize that away.

Comment: That makes total sense! And your right. I am just trying to build a better understanding of the logic behind it. Thank you!